# Node for local mesh curvature

Tags: node-editor

Is there a node (or group of nodes) that outputs a measure of local mesh curvature?

Using the input Fresnel node almost gives me the effect I'm looking for, but the node setup I'm looking for would be unaffected by viewing angle.

Comment: What about the *Normal* output of the geometry node?

Comment: @gandalf3 I think the **amplitude of the gradient/derivative of the _Normal_ map** is what I'm after. I'd like to be able to distinguish regions that are curving from regions that are flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was [added recently](https://developer.blender.org/rB227a94077f508a47fe7595b9091ab86aecde4ad5) and should be in 2.74.

> This attribute means how "pointy" the geometry surface is, which
>   allows to do effects like dirt maps and wear-off effects on render
>   geometry. This means the attribute is calculated for the final mesh
>   which means no baking (which implies UV unwrap) is needed. Apart from
>   this the behavior is quite close to how vertex dirty colors works.
>
> The new attribute is available as an output socket of Geometry node.
>
> There's no penalty for the render time, only some delay on scene
>   preparation (the delay is linear of the mesh complexity).